# Erro the best overload for '.ctor' does not have a parameter named 'throwifv1schema' com entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com um erro que não está fazendo eu não conseguir compilar o projeto.
Estou usando asp.net c# entity framework code first

O erro indica

```
the best overload for '.ctor' does not have a parameter named 'throwifv1schema'

    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    //using PortalAdmCC.AcessoDados;
    using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

    namespace PortalAdmCC.Models
    {
        // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            internal string PhoneNumber;

            public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
            {
                // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
                var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                // Add custom user claims here
                return userIdentity;
            }


            public string AreaSolicitante { get; set; }
            public string Perfil { get; set; }
            public DateTime? LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
            public ApplicationUser()
               : base()
            {
                PreviousUserPasswords = new List<PreviousPassword>();
            }
            public virtual IList<PreviousPassword> PreviousUserPasswords { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; internal set; }
        }


        public class PreviousPassword
        {
            public PreviousPassword()
            {
                CreateDate = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            }

            [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
            public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
            public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
            [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        }


        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("vivo", throwIfV1Schema: false)
            {

            }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                //tira o plural no nome das tabelas
                modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
                //Limita tamanho dos campos string
                modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(255));
                // modelBuilder.Entity()HasRequired( )
                //.Entity().HasRequired(d => d.Administrator).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            }

            public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
            {
                return new ApplicationDbContext();
            }

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        }

    }
```

Meu web.config do projeto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'" />
    <add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'" />

    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=vivo; Integrated Security=False; User ID= sa; Password=382700; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=True; ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite; Connection Timeout=60; MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
    <!--  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=172.16.0.5; Initial Catalog=DB_PROJETO_HOMOLOG; Integrated Security=False; User ID= user_projeto_homologacao; Password=rat4xAr7pra; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=True; ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Download_Data" connectionString = "Data Source=172.16.0.5; Initial Catalog=DB_PROJETO_HOMOLOG; Integrated Security=False; User ID=user_projeto_homologacao; Password=rat4xAr7pra; Encrypt=False; TrustServerCertificate=True; ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>


  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50192" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" publicKeyToken="8fb06cb64d019a17" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.8.0.0" newVersion="2.8.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FastMember.Signed" publicKeyToken="9e8f22703bef9a29" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.1" newVersion="4.1.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="ToastNotifications" publicKeyToken="e89d9d7314a7c797" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.5.0" newVersion="2.2.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Console" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.91.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <!--<location path="ImportaContratosAux">-->
  <!--   <system.web>-->
  <!-- 50MB in kilobytes, default is 4096 or 4MB executionTimeout="3600"-->
  <!--   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200"  />
      </system.web>-->
  <!-- <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering>-->
  <!-- 50MB in bytes, default is 30000000 or approx. 28.6102 Mb-->
  <!--     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />

          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
      </system.webServer>-->
  <!-- </location>-->
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Fuçando mais um pouco cheguei ao IdentityDbContext e notei a seguinte coisa, ele não tem o override que preciso.

Como proceder

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// C:\Users\gabriel.da.c.falieri\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PACO\PortalAdmCC\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll
#endregion

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;

namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
{
    public class IdentityDbContext<TUser> : DbContext where TUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public IdentityDbContext();
        public IdentityDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString);

        public virtual IDbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual IDbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder);
        protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items);
    }
```

Quando coloco só    `public ApplicationDbContext() : base("vivo"){}`

Não funciona

Comment: Ele esta falando que a superclasse de ApplicationDbContext não tem o parâmetro throwIfV1Schema.

Comment: Mas ta ali uai??

Comment: Como corrigir esse problema

Comment: você esta ciente que não esta usando o seu construtor, não é? Perceba que você esta chamando o construtor do método base.

Comment: Cara sou muito novato em asp.net, só quero saber o que resolveria e pronto.

Comment: public ApplicationDbContext() : base("vivo", false) , monte dessa forma..

Comment: Também não deu!!

Comment: Como podemos solucionar isso, sabe??